# Is it inappropriate to recommend two colleagues for the same job?

Tags: colleagues, recommendation-letter

I was recently contacted by a colleague about an available position in my field. Since the field is relatively small, I have had two other colleagues who are changing positions ask me to recommend them for the job and I'm not sure if I did the right thing.

The email I sent read something like this.

> Hi Colleague A,
>
> Thanks for the heads up on this position.
>
> I'd like to introduce you to my colleague, Colleague B (or Colleague C). Here is a description of why they are good for the job
>
> Colleague B (or Colleague C), Here is some description about Colleague A and what she does at the company in question.
>
> Colleague A, I've CCed Colleague B (Or Colleague C) on this e-mail and that should be the best way to get in touch with him about the position at Company X.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Me

I already notified Colleague A that I would be recommending both of them for the position in two separate e-mails. Was it inappropriate of me to recommend both of them even though I think they're both qualified?

Comment: I think this is a opinion question where only your own opinion matters. If you think they're both qualified, and you don't have some reason to favor one to the exclusion of the other, I don't see any reason not to endorse both.

Comment: The only advice is to remember to warn B about the situation. Other than that, no issue at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't actually recommended either of them; you've written a *letter of introduction*.  There's nothing unusual about making multiple introductions like this.

Colleague A will see two letters from you and might wonder about your intentions, so you could send a separate note only to A saying that you know a couple people who would be good fits and you'll be making introductions.  I've done that a few times and it hasn't caused problems; the key is to be clear about what you're doing.  You're introducing A to a couple of good candidates; companies always want to have multiple options because even if *they* like both candidates, both candidates might not end up liking *them*.

Whether you tell B and C about each other depends on what they think you've promised them.  I recommend telling each of them that you'll be happy to make introductions and provide a reference, but you should avoid saying anything that implies exclusivity.

Comment: With regards to paragraph 3: I'd definitely recommend going further and explicitly stating that you will be doing the same for another friend/colleague, so there's no confusion or awkwardness if they discover it later.